# Error on junit tests: Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit4

I'm working on junit test for my java class and I'm getting org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InjectMocksException.

```
[ERROR] testShutdownExecutorService(com.ibm.wce.scbn.api2api.api2apijobs.service.MQMessageCheckerTest) Time elapsed: 8.455 s  <<< ERROR!
    org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InjectMocksException:
    
    Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'mQMessageChecker' of type 'class com.ibm.wce.scbn.api2api.api2apijobs.service.MQMessageChecker'.
    You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
    However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : null
    
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Below is my test class using JUnit 4

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith( MockitoJUnitRunner.class )
public class MQMessageCheckerTest {
    
    @Mock
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    
    @Mock
    RestServiceConnector restServiceConnector;

    @Mock
    TextMessage textMessage;

    @InjectMocks
    MQMessageChecker mQMessageChecker;
    
    @Mock
    ExecutorService executorService;
    
    @Test
    public void testCheckMQForMessages() {
        mQMessageChecker.checkMQForMessages();
    }
```

Here is my java class 'MQMessageChecker', I tried many stuffs but nothing seems to be working

```
public class MQMessageChecker {

@Value("${scbnhub.qname}")
private String queueName;

@Value("${mq.threadPoolMax}")
private int threadPool;

@Autowired
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

@Autowired
RestServiceConnector restServiceConnector;

protected static final String TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPool);


/**
 * scheduler added to make the call frequently
 */
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
public void checkMQForMessages() {
    String selector = TIMESTAMP + " <= " + System.currentTimeMillis();
    receiveAndPrintMessages(queueName, selector);
}
```

[image]

Comment: what caused the IllegalArgumentException? Is the error message you posted the exact error message you get? seems a bit odd to see: "... so I tried to construct the instance" in an actual error message

Comment: yeah, thats the exact message I got.
@Stultuske I aaded the screenshot above for reference

Comment: Spring Boot tests (@SpringBootTest) and Mockito (@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)). 
these two annotations are not typically used together because they serve different purposes and are part of different testing approaches.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove **@SpringBootTest** (used for integration tests)
2. I would recommend using constructor injection instead of filed injection. It`s better practice and easier to maintain and manage